# force a web page to open in private browsing

Tags: wordpress, security, private

Doing some work for a charity and it would be very useful if someone, that is in need, could open the website and be given an option of carry on as normal or if you need help, click a link and that would 
A) force the history to be deleted for the website
B) open the site in incognito/private browsing

Is this possible at all

thanks

Comment: No, you cant force that.  Your best bet would be simple instructions based on the users current browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need one time configuration at browser end as mentioned in the below link

https://www.howtogeek.com/137466/how-to-always-start-any-browser-in-private-browsing-mode/

hope this helps to

Comment: Unfortunately configuring a browser is not possible - it needs to be available to anyone that clicks the site